# TFS - Enabling "Rerun Failed Tests"

Tags: testing, tfs, vstest

I have a TFS Release definition that runs several tests as part of the deployment:

[image]

[image]

When I check the "Rerun Failed Tests" Option in my "Visual Studio Test" step in:

[image]

My unit tests no longer run as part of my release. The release fails with the following error in the "Visual Studio Test" step:

> 2019-02-22T16:21:33.0983821Z ##[error]Error opening response file
>   'C:\TFS' 2019-02-22T16:21:33.1413767Z ##[error]The test source file
>   "C:\TFS Agent\ _work\r6\a\Agent_work_temp\ea14a091-36bd-11e9-99f5-51895cf3942e.txt" provided was not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured since the error started with the following statement:

> Error opening response file 'C:\TFS'

That there is some sort of bug with the TFS test runner where the call to the task to execute the tests is not putting the path in quotes. I changed all my TFS build agents to using the following "type" of paths for all builds(I removed all spaces from the folder the TFS agents lived in):

> C:\TFSAgent\ _work

And it seems to work now...